# DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.run_pipeline is not working because of columnpath is required for JSON type

Tags: sql, json, oracle, rdbms

there!
I'm a new user at DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE, I can't figure out why my code is not working, I only get the same problem every time.
Do you know what could be wrong with my declaration?

Thanks.

```
BEGIN
     DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.CREATE_PIPELINE(
        pipeline_name => 'LOAD_PIPELINE_01',
        pipeline_type => 'LOAD',
        description => 'Load objects...'
  );
END;
/

exec DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.set_attribute('LOAD_PIPELINE_01', 'credential_name', 'Personal_Cred');
exec DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.set_attribute('LOAD_PIPELINE_01', 'table_name', 'persons_source');
exec DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.set_attribute('LOAD_PIPELINE_01', 'format', '{"type": "json"}');
exec DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.set_attribute('LOAD_PIPELINE_01', 'interval', '15');

BEGIN
DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.set_attribute(
pipeline_name   => 'LOAD_PIPELINE_01',
attribute_name  => 'location',
attribute_value => 'https://.../data.json'
);
END;
/


SQL> 
SQL> exec DBMS_CLOUD_PIPELINE.run_pipeline(pipeline_name =>'LOAD_PIPELINE_01');
BEGIN DBMS_CLOUD.*

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: Missing format parameter: columnpath is required for JSON type
ORA-06512
ORA-06512
ORA-06512
```

I already tried all the valid options for "format" mentioned in official [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/format-options.html#GUID-08C44CDA-7C81-481A-BA0A-F7346473B703)

Also tried changing credentials, changing location, verify that pipeline is created, but I keep getting the same error no matter what I change in code.

Comment: In the format attributes, you have to add a columnpath  specification, telling the pipeline which field of the json document corresponds to each column of the target table.